# How to keep an activity in proguard rule?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have to build a release apk in which I have made `minifyEnabled true` and want pro-guard to ignore an activity. How do I do that

my code:

```
-keep public class com.or.pg
```

Answer (score 0):

The build process runs the tool aapt to automatically create the configuration file bin/proguard.txt, based on AndroidManifest.xml and other xml files. The build process then passes the configuration file to ProGuard. So ProGuard itself indeed doesn't consider AndroidManifest.xml, but aapt+ProGuard do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-dontwarn` option in proguard to ignore an activity.

`-dontwarn com.ol.native.Native` whichever you want to ignore

More info here http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/refcard.html

Comment: as i wrote -dontwarn com.ol.native.** is this correct

Comment: this will ignore all classes of com.ol.native package

Comment: i wrote -dontwarn com.ol.native.Native.**

Comment: it will ignore all methods and members of that class plz refer that document from that you will get more info about this

Comment: and how to ingore progressbar

Comment: if progress bar is one of the member of this class then it will automatically ignored